# Consistent start-of-string anchor behavior in .NET Regex Match methods

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Regexes in .NET (I’m using 4.5.2) appear to have three (non-static) Match methods:

1. [`regex.Match(string input)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) searches for the first match in `input`.
2. [`regex.Match(string input, int startIndex)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh(v=vs.110).aspx) searches for the first match in `input` starting at `startIndex`.
3. [`regex.Match(string input, int startIndex, int length)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h09aybcd(v=vs.110).aspx) searches for the first match in a range of `input` defined by `startIndex` and `length`.

If I write

```cs
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex =
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^abc");
string str = "abc abc";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = regex.Match(str);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(match.Success);
```

then I see that `match.Success` is `True`, as expected. The `regex` matches the `abc` at the beginning of `str`.

If I then write

```cs
int index = 4;
match = regex.Match(str, index);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(match.Success);
```

to search from index 4 to the end of `str`, then I see that `match.Success` is `False`, as expected. There’s an `abc` at index 4 of `str`, but index 4 is not the beginning of the string.

However, if I write

```cs
match = regex.Match(str, index, str.Length - index);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(match.Success);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(match.Index);
```

to again search from index 4 to the end of `str`, then I see that `match.Success` is unexpectedly `True`, and `match.Index` is 4. I would expect to get the same result as calling `regex.Match(str, index)`.

Is there a way to get consistent start-of-string anchor behavior in .NET Regex Match methods?

Comment: It seems that using the third parameter causes a new string to be created from the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments in the [*Regex.cs* source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/Regex.cs,803http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/Regex.cs,803), I see that `public Match Match(String input, int startat)` *finds the first match, starting at the specified position* and `public Match Match(String input, int beginning, int length)` *finds the first match, **restricting the search to the specified interval of the char array**.*

Combined with your test results (and [mine](http://ideone.com/tQwxHo)), it is clear that the last overload of the `Regex.Match` method takes the substring as a new, separate string and passes it to the regex engine. No changing `^` to `\A` will help.

Thus, to know if the match is at the real start or not, you should just add logics to your own code, say, if `index` is more than 0, all matches are not at the real start of the string. However, the index returned is correct, thus **that looks like a bug** to me.